# Has border-*-image been removed from the CSS Backgrounds and Borders module?

Tags: css

Can't seem to find any reference to these properties in the latest version of the *CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3*:

- border-top-image, border-right-image, border-bottom-image, border-left-image
- border-top-left-image , border-top-right-image, border-bottom-right-image, border-bottom-left-image
- border-corner-image

The last reference I could find to these properties is in *W3C Working Draft 7 November 2002*. If these properties are removed, does that mean browsers will stop supporting them, which means I should stop using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, these properties have been removed and are replaced by [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image).  `border-image` combines the 4 sides, 4 corners and background image into a single file, which is great for reducing HTTP requests.

Browsers may stop supporting them eventually; it's difficult to predict what each browser vendor will do in the future.  The best practice is certainly to stick to properties which are in the specification, so if it were me, I'd make the upgrades.

Comment: Thanks. I guess then I can't use different images for different sides.

Comment: You can't use different image *files*, but you could just combine your separate border images into one file; sort of like a sprite.

Comment: border-image slicing is not very reliable on webkit - at least apart from very latest chrome